# Php и массивы

Tags: массивы, php

Есть ли стандартная функция для определения входит ли какое либо значение в массив.
Как strrpos() только для массивов.
Если нет, то подскажите максимально правильное решение для данной задачи

Answer (score 4):

```
// по значению
in_array($value, $array)

// по ключу
isset($array[$key])
```

Answer (score 2):

Да! Здесь существует множество всякой всячины. Начиная от "`array_intersect()`", которая возвращает элементы, совпавшие в двух массивах(сравниваемый и исходный), и заканчивая методом "слепки" всех элементов массива в строку и уже потом поиска в ней. Второй вариант можно сделать так:

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$str=implode('',$arr);
$str2 = strpos("34",$str);
echo($str2);  // вывод позиции вхождения в "массив" строки "34"
```